# Pylint detecting entry point script as module

Tags: python, pylint

I have a package which contains a module and an entry-point script with the same name.  I'd like to run `pylint` on all of the files (the entry-point script has more code in it than it should) however it is giving me `no-name-in-module` errors which seem to be because it's detecting the entry-point script as a module instead of the actual module.

Example setup:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── rabbit
└── lib
    ├── lemur.py
    └── rabbit.py
```

`rabbit`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from lemur import lemur
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lemur()
```

`lemur.py`:

```py
from rabbit import RABBIT_NAME
def lemur():
    print(f"I am friends with a rabbit called {RABBIT_NAME}")
```

`rabbit.py`:

```py
RABBIT_NAME = "Ellie"
```

If I run this with Python, it works fine:

```
❯ env PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)/lib" python bin/rabbit
I am friends with a rabbit called Ellie
```

but `pylint` is not happy:

```
❯ env PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)/lib" pylint bin/rabbit lib/* -d all -e E,W
************* Module lemur
lib/lemur.py:1:0: E0611: No name 'RABBIT_NAME' in module 'rabbit' (no-name-in-module)
```

Is it possible to tell `pylint` to ignore the module and ideally just respect my `$PYTHONPATH`?

I tried adding `--init-hook="import sys;sys.path.pop(0)"` to the `pylint` call which removed the `bin` folder from `sys.path` however this did not seem to make a difference.

```
astroid==3.0.1
pylint==3.0.2
```